# Retrieving data from differents tableviews by checkmark in Swift

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

*I have three table view on storyboard. I want to retrieve 3 different data from different tableviews by checkmark. Such as first tableview refer to gender, second one refers to age and the last one is refers to variety How can I retrieve datas from tableview cells

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none {
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        }
        else {
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        }

}
```

Comment: Why not get all three in global variables on selection of each option?

Comment: Unrelated but the duplication of the code is redundant. Just write the code once and use the passed `tableView` parameter.

Comment: @vadian but they are different tableviews

Comment: @TheTiger Because I retrieved datas from firebase in 3 different tuples

Comment: Yes but the `tableView` parameter is always the table view which was selected.

Comment: @BurakNurçiçek **vadian** means use `tableView` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` instead of `tableView_1`, `tableView_2` and `tableView_3`.

Comment: you want to display at a time one table view OR three table view should be displayed at the same time.