# Deleting string from selected checkmark in array at Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, tableview

I want to delete data from unselected row by checkmark. Now I can append strings to my array which are checked. But I want to remove which are unchecked data from array. How can I remove unchecked data from my array ?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    if(tableView == self.tableView_1) {

        if(tableView_1.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none) {
            tableView_1.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark

            checkedItemsForGender.append(cinsiyet[indexPath.row])

        }
        else{
            tableView_1.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none

            checkedItemsForGender.remove(at: cinsiyet[indexPath.row]) // ??? ERROR 
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have two accounts [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9343185/burak-nur%c3%a7i%c3%a7ek) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9342610/burak-nur%c3%a7i%c3%a7ek)? Anyway you haven't made correction in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115367/retrieving-data-from-differents-tableviews-by-checkmark-in-swift#comment87248014_50115367) from another account. :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use this:

```
if let index = checkedItemForGender.index(of: cinsiyet[indexPath.row]) {
checkedItemsForGender.remove(at: index)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `else` as below to fix the `error` and possibility of `index out of bound exception`

```
if let index = checkedItemForGender.index(of: cinsiyet[indexPath.row]),
      index < checkedItemsForGender.count {
     checkedItemsForGender.remove(at: index)
}
```